# Client/Server app works in Eclipse but not as Exported JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, client, server

I wrote a "complex" client/server application which runs in locally in eclipse or an exported runable jar file. However, when I run the exported client jar on another computer in my network it doesn't work.

The remote client connects, I can see it on the locally running client but the remote client doesn't seem to get any messages from the server.

For testing I imported the project into eclipse on the remote client and ran it expecting to see some exceptions. Everything works fine, both clients are able to communicate.

I had this happen with a test version, the same exact symptoms. I fixed it by selecting "Package required libraries into generated JAR" in the export dialog. This time it doesn't work.

The project contains 3 packages: Server, Client, and Message. Message is where I have a serializable class which is the basis for sending the messages. Looking at the exported JAR I can see all three packages with .class files. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and exported again, but the same happens.

I've ran both the exported server and client files on the local machine and was only able to make the remote machine connect using eclipse, not the same exported client jar.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

UPDATE: I exported from a different computer and it works as expected. 2 computers I export from don't work, but one it does. Any suggestions for the 2 computers?

Comment: So you're saying they can't even connect?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party code? Can you get any prints to work from the jar (before network code)?

Comment: The remote client connects. I can see it in the server gui and on the local running client. The button clicks from the remote client are processed by the server and sent to the local client. No third party code was used.